# Start ssh-agent on login

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, redhat, ssh-agent

I have a site as a remote Git repo pulling from Bitbucket.com using an SSH alias. I can manually start the ssh-agent on my server but I have to do this every time I login via SSH.

I manually start the ssh-agent:

```
eval ssh-agent $SHELL
```

Then I add the agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucket_id
```

Then it shows up when I do:

```
ssh-add -l
```

And I'm good to go. Is there any way to automate this process so I don't have to do it every time I login? The server is running RedHat 6.2 (Santiago).

Comment: Anything you want to do every time you login should in .profile (terminal logins) or .xinitrc (for GUI logins).

Comment: Ah! I was using .bash_profile... What's the difference between .profile and .bash_profile?

Comment: @Barmar - It looks like .profile is the correct file name. However it doesn't look like any of the commands after the 'eval ssh-agent $SHELL' is being ran. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why you're running the command that way in the first place. `ssh-agent <command>` runs `<command>` as a subprocess of `ssh-agent`, so you're starting a new shell. I think you want `eval ssh-agent`.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is specific to bash, `.profile` is generic to all POSIX shells. `bash` will look first for `.bash_profile`, then default to `.profile`.

Comment: The correct way to spawn `ssh-agent` for a "standard" (POSIX-compatible) shell is `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`. Note also that you have to make sure you properly get rid of the agent when you log out, so it's also advisable to put `trap 'kill $SSH_AGENT_PID' EXIT` in your `.profile` after the line which starts the agent.

Comment: @Barmar what is wrong with running ssh-agent without eval? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Calicoder The `ssh-agent` command prints environment variable assignments. If you don't use `eval`, they just get printed on the screen, they don't get executed, so the variables don't get set.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Pathsofdesign `ssh-add` says when run without arguments, it adds the files ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/identity.
so `/usr/bin/ssh-add` won't add other private key files together. When using a custom file, I have to modify this script. Am I correct?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited to the Unix SE site where there's a better answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90853/how-can-i-run-ssh-add-automatically-without-password-prompt

Comment: In my opinion, better answers to this question are found here: [Unix & Linux: How can I run ssh-add automatically, without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90853/114401)

Answer (score 537, accepted):

Please go through this article. You may find this very useful:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210506080335/https://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh

Just in case the above link vanishes some day, I am capturing the main piece of the solution below:

> This solution from Joseph M. Reagle by way of Daniel Starin:
>
> Add this following to your **`.bash_profile`**
>
> ```
> SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/agent-environment"
>
> function start_agent {
>     echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."
>     /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
>     echo succeeded
>     chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
>     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
>     /usr/bin/ssh-add;
> }
>
> # Source SSH settings, if applicable
>
> if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
>     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
>     #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
>     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
>         start_agent;
>     }
> else
>     start_agent;
> fi
> ```
>
> This version is especially nice since it will see if you've already started ssh-agent  and, if it can't find it, will start it up and store the settings so that they'll be usable the next time you start up a shell.

Comment: does it need full restart and where it eats '~/.ssh/config ?

Comment: Machine restart is not necessary. You can just reload `.bash_profile` using `source ~/.bash_profile` in your current shell session. Machine restart will also work because that will load the new config anyway.

Comment: Use ``SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/env"`` (i.e. just not /environment)


Why? sshd uses ~/.ssh/environment (see man page : PermitUserEnvironment). 

Github also recommend this in their solution - https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-msysgit

Comment: I call `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` in my `.bachrc` but the already running sshd daemon does not use the newly executed `ssh-agent`. If I log in a few times into my remote server, I'll have a few `ssh-agent`s running but none of them would work. I still would need to log in with a username/pass. After I log in, I can stop sshd and start sshd myself (i.e. `/etc/sbin/sshd -d`), which uses `ssh-agent` but it is not what I want to do. I want `ssh-agent` be loaded automatically when I boot the system even if nobody logs in. I don't have Xserver on my remote system to start ssh-agent for me.

Comment: This script worked for me when I put it in my ~/.bashrc file (not my ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile). The first time I open a local console it prompts for the passphrase, everything works from that point on without further prompting. Cheers.

Comment: Adding the `ssh-agent` start command in .bashrc will make `scp` command not work.

Comment: I removed the `> /dev/null` pieces since I wanted to be notified of errors. You might want to add `-q` to that last `grep`, though, since if you remove `> /dev/null` it will still output the grepped line.

Comment: @Dzanvu I presume you mean `scp` does not work even though you add `ssh-agent` to `.bashrc`. I confirm that. Not sure how to fix that though.

Comment: Finally, if you are using a graphical askpass program (possibly using your DE's password manager), you might have to use `ssh-add </dev/null` i.o. just `ssh-add` else it gives priority to stdin for passphrase input.

Comment: You're a saint! Thank you!!. I closed all my clients and ssh-agent does not ask passphrase!!

Comment: Still annoying... you have to do this every time you log in... even if you don't use ssh.   Need to make this fire off every time ssh is called... and ideally, you should be able to configure which hosts cause which keys to load.

Comment: Creating the .ssh/environment file then chmod 600 leaves it open a a brief time period. It's much more secure to use umask:```OLD_UMASK=$(umask 077); /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"; umask ${OLD_UMASK}```

Comment: This answer is a near-perfect, cross platform solution to make sure ssh-agent just works. But please, clarify in the answer that the file to use is *either* `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. My advice is to use whichever one exists already on your OS. For me, it was `.bash_profile` on OS X and `.bashrc` on Ubuntu 16.04. Other than that, this answer works unchanged in both cases.

Comment: @tobias.mcnulty, I put this in my .bashrc and ensure it is only run for my interactive shells (like `if [[ "$-" == *i* ]] ; then STUFF; fi`).  Placing in .bashrc causes the ssh-agent setup commands to be executed for EVERY shell which might seem overkill, but simplifies your issues with how interactive command shells are started and how environment is passed.  Examples take up more space than comment allows.  When in .bash_profile, commands are ONLY run for "login shells" (bash -l) which may not be how a shell is started (e.g., vim sub-shell).

Comment: @PatS Perhaps OS X terminals are login shells, then, because `.bash_profile` works on OS X, while `.bashrc` does not...

Comment: @tobias.mcnulty Thanks for the info.  I found http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html which states this and recommends adding `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi` to your .bash_profile so you can just maintain one file (.bashrc).

Comment: Like what others here are saying, adding the solution in `~/.bashrc` file works. Thank you!!!

Comment: this somehow broke my svn

Comment: Just a quick note that if you want to load an SSH key other than the default, change the "/usr/bin/ssh-add;" line to "/usr/bin/ssh-add <your key name>;"

Comment: I noticed you're putting (arguably) unecessary semicolons on the last line of your blocks. Why is that? @Litmus

Answer (score 215):

On Arch Linux, the following works really great (should work on all systemd-based distros):

Create a systemd user service, by putting the following to `~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH key agent

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Setup shell to have an environment variable for the socket (`.bash_profile, .zshrc, ...`):

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket"
```

Enable the service, so it'll be started automatically on login, and start it:

```
systemctl --user enable ssh-agent
systemctl --user start ssh-agent
```

Add the following configuration setting to your local ssh config file `~/.ssh/config` (this works since SSH 7.2):

```
AddKeysToAgent  yes
```

This will instruct the ssh client to always add the key to a running agent, so there's no need to ssh-add it beforehand.

Comment: I found this comment while trying to do this in Ubuntu.  It seems to play much more nicely with the built in systems than hacking something into the startup scripts, at least given my knowledge of how the system should work.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Unfortunately, every shell process wants its individual `ssh-agent` process. Perhaps I lack knowledge even after reading the docs.

Comment: You can also use *Type=simple*. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#Start_ssh-agent_with_systemd_user

Comment: so is this solution basically installing/configuring a systemd service (but only for the user)?

Comment: This will not set the `SSH_AGENT_PID` environment variable, though :(

Comment: I like this approach because it makes deployment with Salt dead simple.  Just drop the files and start the service (as opposed to keeping separate `bashrc`s for different kinds of machines)

Comment: @spheenik, can you clarify whether `AddKeysToAgent yes` goes in your local ssh config or the remote?

Comment: This is such a nice clean solution, worked for me on Fedora 31.

Comment: for some reason this is not working for me, do I have generate a key afterwards? this doesn't work for existing keys?

Comment: This is definitely the way to go but the automatic start on login doesn't work for me. I log into another machine via ssh, on which I set up the service to connect to git without password prompt. Is there some special magic needed for ssh-based logins on the machine where I want to run the service?

Comment: I like this answer because it uses the infrastructure specifically designed for running daemons (systemd) and not shell-script hacks with variables.

Comment: why is the step `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK` needed? for me it works without it.

Comment: It is needed so that commands issued in the terminal (for example `ssd-add`) can find the agent. If they can on your machine without configuration, it seems it found the agent in another way.

Comment: I think the solution is the best one. And it just has to be adopted by distros. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client if you want several keys to be tried automatically when connect to git

Comment: For getting the `$SSH_AUTH_TOKEN` to be readable by programs started without reading `.zshrc` (such as VSCode), see this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/637788/297140

Comment: I used this solution on Manjaro and it's working flawlessly. One question though. Why do we have to `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK` again if we've already set the `Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK` value? Shouldn't it be automatically available in your shell?

Comment: The environment declaration in the service is only valid in for the service, and does not propagate to the shell.

Comment: For those who, like me, cross-reference multiple sources before just implementing the first answer they find... This answer is consistent with https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#SSH_agents

Comment: There is systemd-ssh-agent package in AUR for the Arch Linux .

Answer (score 182):

Old question, but I did come across a similar situation. Don't think the above answer fully achieves what is needed. The missing piece is `keychain`; install it if it isn't already.

```
sudo apt-get install keychain
```

Then add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`

```
eval $(keychain --eval id_rsa)
```

This will start the `ssh-agent` if it isn't running, connect to it if it is, load the `ssh-agent` environment variables into your shell, and load your ssh key.

Change `id_rsa` to whichever private key in `~/.ssh` you want to load.

Some useful options for keychain:

- `-q` Quiet mode
- `--noask` Don't ask for the password upon start, but on demand when ssh key is actually used.

**Reference**

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90853/how-can-i-run-ssh-add-automatically-without-password-prompt

Comment: keychain does not work for me according to the instructions given. I added to .bash_profile and ssh still asks for password every time. i tried it multiple times in same shell. no dice. going back to basic ssh-agent approach

Comment: This is the correct and simple solution. If you do not want to see the log when keychain command is executed, you can add `-q` option for quiet mode. More info about Keychain: https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain

Comment: @James The `$(`....`)` *is* better than using backticks! See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449778/4805858 ...

Comment: Works great! FWIW, I also appended `2> /dev/null` inside `$(...)` to suppress reported information from keychain.

Comment: The [linked reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90853/how-can-i-run-ssh-add-automatically-without-password-prompt) gives by far the most complete answer to this question. It details all the possible approaches to this and their tradeoffs.

Comment: This is the the most elegant and efficient solution and works without issues in a virtual linux environment on chromebook (arm build) too. Specifically it works with git and visual studio code.

Comment: This solution as it stands currently "eval $(keychain --eval id_rsa)" didn't work for me until I added "--agents ssh " parameter to keychain, as it is recommended in the linked solution.

Comment: How should I modify this to add ALL my private keys at once? --eval ~/.ssh/* fails because it tries to everything, but files like *.pub or known_hosts or config aren't private keys, so it fails.

Comment: This works perfectly for Ubuntu 20.04.2. For all the Oh My ZSH users, instead of updating `~/.bashrc`, update `~/.zshrc` instead

Comment: On my i3 system, GDM runs `bash /etc/gdm3/Xsession i3` which has the result of running `keychain` and trying to ask for the passphrase before i3 has finished loading, which blocks everything completely. I can put it after the PS1 (interactive) check in `.bashrc` but then I lose the ability for remote scripts to pick up the keychain, which is a useful aspect. Any improvements on this?

Comment: "--noask Don't ask for the password upon start, but on demand when ssh key is actually used."
Doesn't work, authentication fails for me without asking for a passphrase.

Comment: This worked great for me on Pop OS 22.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 45):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`, then logout and back in to take effect.

```bash
if [ ! -S ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ]; then
  eval `ssh-agent`
  ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add
```

This should only prompt for a password the first time you login after each reboot. It will keep reusing the same `ssh-agent` as long as it stays running.

Comment: What would we use instead if we had multiple keys and they weren't named `~/.ssh/id_rsa`? It seems that the `ssh-add` part of your answer expects  default file names for the keys.

Comment: Yup. I believe you can just add the file names to to the very end of the last line if needed

Comment: But you still cant automize a script do pull git stuff for example without entering password manually? How to avoid that?

Comment: Some improvements could be done to this script: 1/ in place of creating a soft link we can ask `ssh-agent` to directly create the socket in our homedir with option `-a ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} (note that the export of var SSH_AUTH_SOCK need to be declare a bit before). 2/ in place of having the ssh-add prompting at the first login, you could add the `AddKeysToAgent` to yes in your ssh config to add at the first ssh, so you will be prompted for your passphrase at first ssh connection not login. 3/ the eval notation could use `$(ssh-agent)` notation and ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} for the shell var.

Comment: This works for me, and i use a dmenu for the prompt because i did the default ```x11-ssh-askpass```. Can put a script containing a simple like ```dmenu -fn Monospace-18 -p "$1" <&- && echo``` and put it in your ```PATH```. Then tell ssh to use this script instead by exporting ```SSH_ASKPASS=script```

Answer (score 41):

The accepted solution have following drawbacks:

- it is complicated to maintain;
- it evaluates storage file which may lead to errors or security breach;
- it starts agent but doesn't stop it which is close equivalent to leaving the key in ignition.

If your keys do not require to type password, I suggest following solution. Add the following to your `.bash_profile` **very end** (edit key list to your needs):

```
exec ssh-agent $BASH -s 10<&0 << EOF
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_key1.rsa \
            ~/.ssh/your_key2.rsa &> /dev/null
    exec $BASH <&10-
EOF
```

It have following advantages:

- much simpler solution;
- agent session ends when bash session ends.

It have possible disadvantages:

- interactive `ssh-add` command will influence only one session, which is in fact an issue only in very untypical circumstances;
- unusable if typing password is required;
- started shell becomes non-login (which doesn't influence anything AFAIK).

Note that several `ssh-agent` processes is not a disadvantage, because they don't take more memory or CPU time.

Comment: I've got SSH keys in a directory outside of $HOME in Windows 10, using Git Bash. Changing the path to the RSA was all I needed to do to get this working. TYVM!

Comment: I would argue that **"If your keys do not require to type password"** is close equivalent to leaving the key in ignition.

Comment: At least, it is on your own host, not somewhere on the network.

Comment: "I would argue that "If your keys do not require to type password" is close equivalent to leaving the key in ignition. " <-- Explain how so??  

Because keys are far more flexible than passwords, far easier to revoke (what? You're only using keys for sudo users with full access? tsk tsk). Multiple sets of keys for multiple profiles of users.  If you want to automate anything (like deployment, or end to end checks) then good luck constantly typing in passwords during "orchestration".

Comment: Don't do that. Passwordless keys are a bad practice.

Comment: There are people who live in the world of theft and treachery and there are people who live in the world of friendship. It's your choice of course: do you want to spend time on passwords, locks, certificates, fingerprints, etc. If you are afraid of course use "best practices" and remember and type long and hard meaningless strings. But there more interesting things to do. Btw, I'm not saying you don't have to lock anything. I'm just saying that Goble, Micro$oft, Fapple, etc. call paranoid lifestyle on you, but it's always your choice to select level of security according to stakes involved.

Comment: @midenok Hello 
after adding this on my .bash_profile and loging out i cant access my server from my terminal. 
i tried severel times but i can access my server right now what can i do now? 
it gives me this error 
**ec2-user@1.2.3.4.5: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).**

Answer (score 17):

Tried couple solutions from many sources but all seemed like too much trouble. Finally I found the easiest one :)

If you're not yet familiar with **[zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH)** and **[oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/README.md)** then install it. You will love it :)

Then edit `.zshrc`

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

find `plugins` section and update it to use `ssh-agent` like so:

```
plugins=(ssh-agent git)
```

And that's all! You'll have `ssh-agent` up and running every time you start your shell

Comment: But not at login. zshrc is only sourced when the user opens a terminal

Answer (score 11):

Just to add yet another solution :P, I went with a combination of @spheenik and @collin-anderson 's solutions.

```bash
 # Ensure that we have an ssh config with AddKeysToAgent set to true
 if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/config ] || ! cat ~/.ssh/config | grep AddKeysToAgent | grep yes > /dev/null; then
     echo "AddKeysToAgent  yes" >> ~/.ssh/config
 fi
 # Ensure a ssh-agent is running so you only have to enter keys once
 if [ ! -S ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ]; then
   eval `ssh-agent`
   ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
 fi
 export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
```

Could be a little more elegant but its simple and readable. This solution:

- ensures `AddKeysToAgent yes` is in your ssh config so keys will be automatically added upon use
- doesn't prompt you to enter any passphrases at login (again, one-time passphrase entering occurs on first use)
- silently starts an ssh-agent if it has not already started one

Comments welcome :)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. On Kubuntu I put it in .profile.

Comment: Good to know about the `AddKeysToAgent yes` setting. Thanks.

Comment: This did not work for me, because the `! -S` always evaluated to `false` even when `ssh-agent` had terminated. The script thus only worked once.

Answer (score 8):

So I used to use the approaches described above, but I kind of prefer the agent to die when my last bash session ends. This is a bit longer than the other solutions, but its my preferred approach. The basic idea is that the first bash session starts the ssh-agent. Then each additional bash session checks for the config file (`~/.ssh/.agent_env`). If that is there and there is a session running then source the environment and create a hardlink to the socket file in `/tmp` (needs to be on the same filesystem as the original socket file). As bash sessions shut down each deletes its own hardlink. The last session to close will find that the hardlinks have 2 links (the hardlink and the original), removal of the processes own socket and killing of the process will result in 0, leaving a clean environment after the last bash session closes.

```sh
# Start ssh-agent to keep you logged in with keys, use `ssh-add` to log in
agent=`pgrep ssh-agent -u $USER` # get only your agents           
if [[ "$agent" == "" || ! -e ~/.ssh/.agent_env ]]; then
    # if no agents or environment file is missing create a new one
    # remove old agents / environment variable files
    kill $agent running
    rm ~/.ssh/.agent_env 

    # restart
    eval `ssh-agent` 
    echo 'export SSH_AUTH_SOCK'=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK >> ~/.ssh/.agent_env             
    echo 'export SSH_AGENT_PID'=$SSH_AGENT_PID >> ~/.ssh/.agent_env             
fi

# create our own hardlink to the socket (with random name)           
source ~/.ssh/.agent_env                                                    
MYSOCK=/tmp/ssh_agent.${RANDOM}.sock                                        
ln -T $SSH_AUTH_SOCK $MYSOCK                                                
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$MYSOCK                                                

end_agent()                                                                     
{
    # if we are the last holder of a hardlink, then kill the agent
    nhard=`ls -l $SSH_AUTH_SOCK | awk '{print $2}'`                             
    if [[ "$nhard" -eq 2 ]]; then                                               
        rm ~/.ssh/.agent_env                                                    
        ssh-agent -k                                                            
    fi                                                                          
    rm $SSH_AUTH_SOCK                                                           
}                                                                               
trap end_agent EXIT                                                             
set +x
```

Comment: if we run this as a BASH script on login of any other shell (other then BASH), it should work too, right?

Comment: I actually now just use keychain (see above)

Comment: Could you please shortly explain the line `kill $agent running`? I understand what `kill $agent` means, but what does `running` mean? According to `man kill`, there is no such parameter. Otherwise, I like the principle of your solution. Quite elegant ...

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by adding this to the */etc/profile* - system wide (or to user local *.profile*, or *.bash_profile*):

```sh
# SSH-AGENT 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SERVICE='ssh-agent'
WHOAMI=`whoami |awk '{print $1}'`

if pgrep -u $WHOAMI $SERVICE >/dev/null
then
    echo $SERVICE running.
else
    echo $SERVICE not running.
    echo starting
    ssh-agent > ~/.ssh/agent_env
fi
. ~/.ssh/agent_env
```

This starts a new ssh-agent if not running for the current user, or re-sets the ssh-agent env parameter if running.

Comment: Thank you for saying how to tell if the agent is already running!

Comment: How does the `if pgrep -u $WHOAMI $SERVICE >/dev/null` work?

Answer (score 4):

Users of the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) can use this [script](https://gist.github.com/gerbsen/5fd8aa0fde87ac7a2cae) to do the same thing.

```fish
# content has to be in .config/fish/config.fish
# if it does not exist, create the file
setenv SSH_ENV $HOME/.ssh/environment

function start_agent                                                                                                                                                                    
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent ..."
    ssh-agent -c | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > $SSH_ENV
    echo "succeeded"
    chmod 600 $SSH_ENV 
    . $SSH_ENV > /dev/null
    ssh-add
end

function test_identities                                                                                                                                                                
    ssh-add -l | grep "The agent has no identities" > /dev/null
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]
        ssh-add
        if [ $status -eq 2 ]
            start_agent
        end
    end
end

if [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ] 
    ps -ef | grep $SSH_AGENT_PID | grep ssh-agent > /dev/null
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]
        test_identities
    end  
else
    if [ -f $SSH_ENV ]
        . $SSH_ENV > /dev/null
    end  
    ps -ef | grep $SSH_AGENT_PID | grep -v grep | grep ssh-agent > /dev/null
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]
        test_identities
    else 
        start_agent
    end  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I like your answers a lot. It made working from `cygwin / linux` hosts a lot easier. I combined start and end functions to make it secure.

```sh
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/.agent_env"

function start_agent {
    echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."

    eval `/usr/bin/ssh-agent`
    echo 'export SSH_AUTH_SOCK'=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK >> ${SSH_ENV}
    echo 'export SSH_AGENT_PID'=$SSH_AGENT_PID >> ${SSH_ENV}

    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add;
}

# Source SSH settings, if applicable
if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
    ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi

# create our own hardlink to the socket (with random name)
MYSOCK=/tmp/ssh_agent.${RANDOM}.sock
ln -T $SSH_AUTH_SOCK $MYSOCK
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$MYSOCK

end_agent()
{
    # if we are the last holder of a hardlink, then kill the agent
    nhard=`ls -l $SSH_AUTH_SOCK | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [[ "$nhard" -eq 2 ]]; then
        rm ${SSH_ENV}
        /usr/bin/ssh-agent -k
    fi
    rm $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
}
trap end_agent EXIT
set +x
```

Comment: Great idea! Perhaps it would be more reliable though if you used the bash process' PID and the current user's name with `$$` and `${USER}` instead of `${RANDOM}`? Also, the `$(command)` syntax is the new way to do command substitution.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [ssh-ident](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident) tool for this.

From its *man*-page:

> ssh-ident - Start and use ssh-agent and load identities as necessary.