# How to make a script to perform git pull?

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

It is a common practice to perform `git pull` on **dev**/**staging**/**production** server(s). I frequently do so myself; I perform git pull almost 100 times a day on my production server running linux.

I figure, it's time to make a **script** to improve that.

---

**pull.sh** will do these 3 commands

- git pull
- enter my-password (when prompt)
- service nginx reload

---

I've tried create my **pull.sh** here

```
#!/bin/bash

function pull {
  git pull
  password
  service nginx reload
}


pull ;
```

---

**Result**

After running the script that I have, I still got prompt to input the password.

[image]

---

Any hints / helps / suggestions will be much appreciated !

Comment: Which application asks you to enter your password?

Comment: What have you tired. What sites have you visited in the process? This is not exactly a research site in the sense you are looking for.

Comment: Every time, I perform `git pull` it usually prompt me for a password.

Comment: That would be the remote via `ssh` most likely.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : I updated my posted to show you what I got so far.

Comment: Why `eval` everywhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `expect` script to interact with git authentication:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn git pull
expect "ass"
send "your_password\r"
interact
```

It waits for "ass" text (that matches "Password", "password", "passphrase") and then it sends your password.

That script can be called from another bash script that will restart your server:

```
# Call script directly since the shell knows that it should run it with
# expect tool because of the first script line "#!/usr/bin/expect -f"
./git-pull-helper-script.sh
# Without the first line "#!/usr/bin/expect -f" the file with commands
# may be sent explicitly to 'expect':
expect file-with-commands

# Restart server
service nginx reload
```

Comment: This is a legit question, I don't know why 2 people vote it for close. I really appreciated your concern and helps. :)

Comment: @ihue you need to adjust the prompt string to your "Enter...".

Comment: Will do. Do you mind explain a little bit  what is `bin/expect -f` ?

Comment: `\r` and `interact` ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't I place `service nginx reload` under interact command ?

Comment: `#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f` it tell to your system to handle the script by `expect` application: http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect Expect reads cmdfile for a list of commands to execute. Expect may also be invoked implicitly on systems which support the #! notation by marking the script executable, and making the first line in your script.

Comment: This script is not handled by bash. It is interpreted by another application `expect`. Once the expect script is finished you can run other shell commands as `service nginx reload`

Comment: Thank-you very much for your explaination.

Answer (score 3):

The way to handle a passphrase is to use an ssh agent: that way, you only need to type in your passphrase once.

I have this in my dev user's `~/.bash_profile`

```
# launch an ssh agent at login, so git commands don't need to prompt for password
# ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18915067/7552

SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/env

if [[ -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa ]]; then
    function start_agent {
        # Initialising new SSH agent...
        ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#&/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
        chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
        source "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
        ssh-add
    }

    # Source SSH settings, if applicable

    if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
        source "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
        agent_pid=$(pgrep ssh-agent)
        (( ${agent_pid:-0} == $SSH_AGENT_PID )) || start_agent
        unset agent_pid
    else
        start_agent
    fi
fi
```