# Could not sshing into dcos node using dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, mesos, dcos

I am new in dcos Mesos, installed dc os in local Ubuntu machine.

I can view the dcos dashboard.

but I can not sshing the master node using `dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader`. It says:

> There is no `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env variable, which likely means you aren't running `ssh-agent`.  `dcos node ssh --master-proxy/--proxy-ip` depends on `ssh-agent` to safely use your private key to hop between nodes in your cluster.  Please run `ssh-agent`, then add your private key with `ssh-add`.

as [documentation](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/sshcluster/), there should be .pem file in ./ssh directory. But in my Ubuntu machine I did not find .pem file of that location.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your key to your ssh agent: 
This is usually done by `ssh-add keyname`, which requires your [ssh-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880024/start-ssh-agent-on-login) to run.

If you don't file a pem file, this usually means you haven't generated a key before. Use `ssh-keygen` to do so.

BTW, you are referencing an old version of the documentation, I assume you are probably running a 1.9 or 1.10 cluster, so I would make sure to use the respective documentation.

Comment: use ssh-keygen created pem file. I saw there are two files (1).pem (2) .pem.pub.When I run ssh-add <fileName>. it says Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: This could help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48863/ssh-add-complains-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/48868