# Need to issue ssh-agent command every time I start git-bash

Tags: windows, ssh, git-bash

I'm using Windows 7. My company has some repos stored on our own git server. Recently I also had to use GitHub, but ever since I've accessed the repo that's on GitHub, git-bash has been acting really wonky.

What it all boils down to is that every time I open git-bash, if I try do a pull, I get: "error: cannot span git: No such file or directory."

My git version is 2.18.0.windows.1

I've found that I manually have to execute this command every time I launch git-bash:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

I've tried using the info here:
[Start ssh-agent on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880024/start-ssh-agent-on-login)

And here:
https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows

My .profile consists of the following:

```
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

But nope...I still need to manually execute that command whenever I start git -bash. (And the above code is supposed to quash that necessity.)

Answer (score 0):

Both of those links suggests adding that in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` (see "[What are the functional differences between `.profile` `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`](https://serverfault.com/a/261807/783)")

Try that first, instead of using `.profile`.

Make sure your git bash does `echo $HOME` to the expected value: `set HOME` first to `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: I added that to all three - .profile, .bash_profile, and .bashrc. No difference.

echo $HOME is reflecting the correct value.

Comment: @dauber "`cannot span git: No such file or directory.`": is git in your `$PATH` once the bash is opened? Does a `which git` returns something?