# git ssh authentication fails with ssh_askpass: posix_spawn: Unknown error

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, scoop-installer

I am using a setup on Windows 10 x64 where I install and manage git via scoop, rather downloading and executing the installer myself. Via the PowerShell, I ran

```
scoop install git
scoop install openssh
[environment]::setenvironmentvariable('GIT_SSH', (resolve-path (scoop which ssh)), 'USER')
```

However, now when I try to run commands in the *Git Bash* like

```
git clone git@example.org:vendor/repository.git
```

or a simple

```
git push/pull
```

I only get

```
CreateProcessW failed error:193
ssh_askpass: posix_spawn: Unknown error
```

instead of the Git Bash asking me for my SSH key's passphrase.

I am using the same setup (git installed via scoop) on many other Windows 10 x64 and no problems occur there. So I am not sure what is going wrong on this one. I previously had git installed without scoop on the same machine and the Git Bash was working fine. I uninstalled git completely (and also restarted the machine, just to be sure) before re-installing it via *scoop* instead.

The `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable contains the following, in case this is relevant:

```
$ echo ${SSH_ASKPASS}
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
```

Not sure what that folder refers to (something internal to the *Git Bash* presumably?), since it obviously does not exist like that on my machine.

#### Update

When using [`git-with-openssh`](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/blob/master/bucket/git-with-openssh.json) instead of just [`git`](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/blob/master/bucket/git.json) and `openssh` separately it works. However, I don't use that on my other machines, so I'd still like to know why it's not working here.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: @SovietFrontier apparently it is recommended to always use `git-with-oppenssh` due to various issues, instead of using `git` and `openssh` separately.

Comment: is there some instructions on how to set all that up?

Comment: Just do `scoop uninstall git`, `scoop uninstall openssh`, `scoop install git-with-openssh` and run the commands that are displayed in the console output afterwards.

Comment: In my machine it's still broken, even after I replaced `git` with `git-with-openssh`.

Comment: I came to this page with the same error but *not related to scoop*. In my case, it was a conflict between OpenSSH from Git Bash and Windows 10. The solution was a mix between the solution proposed by @rsenna and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18915067/2626480)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure my answer does not address the OP's original case. But as of 2020, there seems to be a similar issue with a different way of solving it, and that's how I did in my case.

Part of the problem is, now Windows 10 has [its own version of OpenSSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview) available, and at least in the case of my work's machine it seems that option is enabled by default.

This bundled OpenSSH is not compatible with Git bash though, so if you wants to use it, you must force git use scoop's provided OpenSSH (either from `openssh` or `git-with-openssh` packages). That means overwriting `GIT_SSH` environment variable, e.g. by adding a line similar to this to your .bashrc:

```
export GIT_SSH='C:\Users\rogs\scoop\apps\git-with-openssh\current\usr\bin\ssh.exe'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, after installing `git` and `openssh` via _Scoop_, that what you are supposed to do anyway. But in my case, when using `git` and `openssh` separately, it still did not work.

Comment: But that's the point, I had to do this even after installing `git-with-openssh`.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this topic is already very old, the problem persists. I found out that its enough to simply unset the environment variable to get rid of this error.

```
unset SSH_ASKPASS
```

Just put this in your `.bash_profile` and/or your `.bashrc`.