# Cannot clone GitHub SSH Repository: CreateProcessW failed error:193

Tags: git, github, ssh, openssh

This is what I am doing and I keep getting this:
[image: error]

I tried:

- checking my ssh key on GitHub, generating new one
- uninstalling and installing the Git from https://git-scm.com/download/win
- uninstalling and istalling OpenSSH from Windows Apps&Features / Optional Features
- installing git via scoop, as well git-with-openssh as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636396/git-ssh-authentication-fails-with-ssh-askpass-posix-spawn-unknown-error)
- changing the GIT_SSH environment variable to correct path in scoop git-with-openssh and checking it in both user and system environment variables
- googling

Notes:

- I have no problem cloning the repository via https
- When I cloned the repository via https through GitHub desktop, then changed the link in GitHub desktop to ssh it got stuck at after push
- I think I am missing something as I cannot imagine there are or there is something wrong, help please :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62832481/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+CreateProcessW+failed+error%3A+193

Comment: Are you using an antivirus other than the default or any other sort of monitoring software?  Those can interfere with spawning processes.

Comment: You mean ssh-agent spawn? You see there is one with pid in the beginning and the process is still in Task Manager when I try to clone.

Comment: @MartinJasso Is your private key passphrase-protected? Because if not, you don't even need ssh-agent in the first place.

Comment: I guess not, according to this:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129724/how-to-check-if-an-ssh-private-key-has-passphrase-or-not

Beginning of my key:
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAACmFlczI1Ni1jdHIAAAAGYmNyeXB0AAAAGAAAABCanl1oD

What does it mean that I dont need an agent? That I dont need to run the eval? I tried that and this is what I got: https://i.imgur.com/hEHZ9AY.png

Answer (score 4):

As illustrated by [`git-for-windows/git` issue 2380](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2380), make sure to:

- delete/unset the `GIT_SSH` environment variable.
  In particular, it should *not* reference `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`
- set your PATH in order to have `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` *before* `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did this. I unistalled the scoop version git-with-openssh, and installed git from https://git-scm.com/download/win. I checked the paths, they are exactly as you are saying, but I still keep getting the same error.

However there is different output in the beginning https://i.imgur.com/LwiYP8q.png