# Python subprocess failed when called from service

Tags: python, linux, service, subprocess

Below simple scripts, used to list keys in ssh-agent:

**list_keys.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh-add -l
```

**list_keys.py**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    Creates log
    """
    ...

    print("Start")
    print subprocess.check_output(["/root/list_keys.sh"])
```

It works well when called directly from the terminal.

```
$python list_keys.py
```

The log shows as expected:

```
Start
2048 SHA256:+gkk***************************nQ .ssh/my_key (RSA)
```

But when I tried to make it as service, it fails.

```
Start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/list_keys.py", line 43, in <module>
print subprocess.check_output(["/root/list_keys.sh"])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess
.
CalledProcessError
:
Command '['/root/list_keys.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

The service config:

**list_keys.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=List Keys Service
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /root/list_keys.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm working on Centos 7. Any clue how to make the **list_keys.py** as service?

Comment: Could it be that you need to specify the full path to list_keys.py in the service definition, and to list_keys.sh in the Python file? When you run it in the terminal, does it work if you call it from a different folder?

Comment: Edited. Actually the full path is there, I just cut it in post for simplicity. Anyway, it won't print "Start" if the script cannot be found. I think its not about the incorrect path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is not in the subprocess. When the script called from service, it has a different session than the ones from the terminal. That's why "ssh-add -l" fails because of no ssh-agent established in that session. Added script to establishing ssh-agent in "list_keys.sh" solved my problem.

Reference on [how to establish ssh-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880024/start-ssh-agent-on-login).

The python subprocess has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot the execution bit on your shell file, easily fixed by:

```
chmod +x list_keys.sh
```

The next candidate would be the full path to `ssh-add`:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-add
```

Comment: Nope, list_keys.sh: 0755/-rwxr-xr-x, also changed to /usr/bin/ssh-add still same result.