# I need to re-run eval(ssh-agent) and ssh-add on every boot

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm wondering if I could get some help. I recently reinstalled my OS and I'm running into a strange issue that I've never run into before. I'm following the [Github steps to add ssh agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Basically, every time I log in I need to run

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_personal
```

when I reboot my computer.

When I try to run `git clone X` I'm getting

```
Cloning into 'X'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

but after I run the above 2 commands, I can clone just fine

Note: issue is also with Gitlab. Sorry, I should have been explicit

Comment: See all answers for https://stackoverflow.com/q/18880024/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh-agent%5D+every+login

Comment: Personally I use `gpg-agent` in `ssh-agent` mode. It stores keys forever in a file and allows to configure how often it re-asks passphrase; mine asks every 12 hours. I start `gpg-agent` before XWin so it's available for all terminals and programs inside my X session.

Comment: MacOS starts an ssh-agent via launchd at the time you log on, before firing up any windows, so that the windows have the ssh environment variables pre-set. You *can* get Linux software that will do the same thing, but I have never used it. I use something much more like the method @phd describes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It sounds like you're running on Linux, and your login is probably "bash".

If so, I would consider adding these two lines to the bottom of your [~/.bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129144/431327) login file:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_personal
```

---

You might also consider trying this:

- [How to Set ssh-agent to Run Automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4078/6jd6cjrub/index.html)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Linux but I'm running on `zsh`. I could probably place those two lines at the bottom of my `.zshrc` (and I will) but I'm also not sure why this is happening.... I've been using linux for quite a while now and I've never seen anything like this

Comment: This doesn't really have that much to do with Linux, but everything to do with GitHub and the way its authentication interacts with a running ssh-agent.

Comment: Sorry, I should habe been more clear and said this, but I'm running into the same issue with gitlab :/

Comment: For bash, since you only want to do this at initial login, you might consider using `.bash_profile`. I'm not sure about the zsh setup. Another common trick is to first *check* whether there's an existing agent available, and if not, start one, but that has some potential races, so I dislike this one myself.

Comment: @IanQ: 1) In case you didn't notice my update, please consider this: [How to Set ssh-agent to Run Automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4078/6jd6cjrub/). 2) phd made an interesting suggestion about using gpg-agent (part of GNUPrivacy Guard) as an alternative to ssh-agent.  You can learn more here: https://gnupg.org/, 3) As you probably already know, the zsh user init file is [~.zshrc](https://linuxhint.com/configure-setup-zshrc-zsh/).  'Hope that helps; please post back what you learn!

Comment: Yeap! Sorry for the silence - work got crazy. Will test out when I'm free

Comment: If you're curious about what's the difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile.

Go to https://cloudzy.com/knowledge-base/what-is-linux-bashrc-and-how-to-use-it-full-guide/#Bashrc_vs_bash_profile

Answer (score 6):

Try this, I found it somewhere online. **Add this to your ~/.bashrc file**

```
    if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
    eval `ssh-agent -s`
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/<NAME OF YOUR PRIVATE KEY>
    fi
```

This assumes your private key is located under .ssh. Otherwise, use the adequate path

Comment: best answer so far as this will not run new ssh-agent on every new terminal you open

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own answer:

I think the issue was that when I made the first key, I changed the name from the default. I.e I changed from

```
~/.ssh/id_id_edX -> ~/.ssh/id_personal
```

After removing the key and regenerating things it all worked out. Why? IDK

Comment: Ah. That is because ssh needs to be given the file and path to that `id_id_edX` key, using the `-i` option (or use IdentityFile as a Host directive in ssh config). Basically SSH has a list of built-in SSH key "names" it will automatically look for and submit to hosts.  You can also create a config that Also, your instinct here to create specific keys for specific use-cases or sites, is a good one (if you don't mind tracking which key goes to which role). It should never be too painful to have to re-generate a key if you suspected it was leaked/lost.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you mentioned using zsh for your shell. You can add ssh-agent to your plugins and it’ll handle it for you.

Comment: Any guide please?

Comment: please elaborate more