# How to write a shell script to pass ssh-add private-key's passphrase?

Tags: linux, git, shell, ssh, ssh-agent

I am writing an appliation that will run a shell scripts behind the scene.
The command that I run in the script looks like this,

```
cd ~/.ssh/ && ssh-add -D && ssh-add <id_rsa_filename>
```

It is trying to add a private key to the ssh agent.

When this command(s) finishes running, and if the ssh private key requires a passphrase, then you get this output from the ssh agent - "Enter passphrase:"

I would like to know,

1. If it is possible to pass a passphrase as an argument while running the ssh-add,
   example: `ssh-add -pass <my_pass_phrase>`
2. How can I change my script to interact with the ssh-agent to pass the passphrase when prompted.

**Important:** I do not wish to remove the passphrase tied to the ssh-private key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make ssh-add read passphrase from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033799/how-to-make-ssh-add-read-passphrase-from-a-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+ssh-add+passphrase+stdin

Comment: Unless your distro has patched them, `ssh` and `ssh-add` only read from a TTY.

Comment: @bk2204 Solution using `expect` is also shown in the linked answer.