# Start ssh-agent when windows boots along with ssh passphrase

Tags: github, ssh, continuous-integration

I have a **private Github repo**, and I generated the SSH keys using windows.

I am trying to launch ssh-agent when my **windows server starts**, I can have the following command..

```
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

but the problem with this is...I would need to enter the passphrase for my SSH key everytime i reboot.

I am working with a github repo, where whenever we commit a change then it triggers the GIT PULL on the server (using webhooks).

Anyway I can automate this?

Comment: Same kind of question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61735998/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make sure your `.profile` (called by `sh --login -i`) includes a [call to `ssh-agent` with a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13034313/6309):

```
cat passfile | ssh-add -p keyfile
```

That way, every time the shell starts, the agent includes your key with its passphrase.