# Windows batch file - start git bash and run git commands

Tags: git, batch-file, windows-10

I am on [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10). I want to create a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to automate:

1. Starting Git Bash in project folder
2. Running the following Git commands:

   ```
   eval $(ssh-agent -s) 
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
   git remote add origin git@github.com:git_user_name/git_repository_name.git
   ```

My current batch file below successfully starts Git Bash in the project folder, but I have not found anything which helps me learn how to run the [git](/questions/tagged/git) commands.

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\project_folder
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i <== edited per suggestion
```

Comment: You want to invoke `sh.exe -c "commands here"`.  Don't use `--login` or `-i` unless you're planning on typing the commands manually.

Comment: BTW, `"%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\sh.exe"` would be more succinct, and no less robust.

Comment: so the next line in my batch file would be  `sh.exe -c "eval $(ssh-agent -s)"` . I did want to have those three commands run and then have git bash open so i could continue to use it manually eg `git add . ` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With direction from comment from bk2204 about "invoking `sh.exe -c`"  I found that the following worked.

I concatenated all 3 commands into one string and put this string after `start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" -c` and also added `; bash` to the end of the command string which keeps the Git bash command window open. I wanted window open so I could continue to use it eg by entering manually `git add ., git commit, push origin master, etc`

```
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" -c "eval $(ssh-agent -s) && 
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa && 
    git remote add origin git@github.com:git_user_name/git_repository_name.git; bash"
```