# How to pass password of ssh key with ssh-add command in a script?

Tags: bash, ssh

I would like to run a git pull with ssh key in a script.

However, password of the ssh-key is required and I did not find anything in the man page that says we can give password as parameter.

I am looking for something like this (if possible):

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)

ssh-add mykey -p keypassword
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Does this help [How to make ssh-add read passphrase from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13033799/5291015)

Comment: @Inian unfortunatly not. I am always asked to give password of the key manually.

Comment: Never mind, got it now.