# How can I pass a password to git in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash, git

I'm working on a small ruby script that will checkout and sync a branch on two different servers. I'm trying to figure out how to pass a password to git when pulling. Right now I have

```
Net::SSH.start(host, user, password: password) do |ssh|
  # other code....
  result = ssh.exec!("git pull")
  # results in Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa'
end
```

After running the git command it get a prompt for the key passphrase.

Is it possible to pass that in with a git command? Or is there another way to do that within ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [net-ssh documetation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net%2FSSH.start) does mention the method `Net::SSH.start()` accepts a passphrase argument:

> `passphrase`
> the passphrase to use when loading a private key (default is nil, for no passphrase)

So if you can get the passphrase (from a file or environment variable) in your program, you can add that argument to the `Net::SSH.start()` method.

Once you are connected, however, it is best to:

- use a passphrase-less key for Git SSH URL
- or use an HTTPS URL instead, for `git pull` commands, since you can register once and for all the password (not passphrase) associated with that HTTPS URL in a credential storage.

Using a passphrase means adding to your SSH session:

- running the ssh-agent
- entering the [passphrase through a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13034313/6309)

That seems quite cumbersome.

Comment: How can I pass in a general password when I've SSHed into the machine? I've been using that to get into it but, I have not been able to pass the password to git afterwards.

Comment: @sneakyfishies I have edited the answer to answer your comment.