What to do with ssh passphrase in shell script?
I want to make zsh script to commit and push everything (i'm making autobackup for obsidian vault), but i don't know what to do with ssh passphrase. Is it possible to fill it automaticly, or ask for it explisitly?
My script:
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add *pathToMySSH*

git add --all

git commit -am "backup"

git push

I expect script to just push a commit silently or with some popup asking me for ssh passphrase

This question is similar to: SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671286/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734873/7976758

This seems like a really bad idea, to be honest. That script will happily commit unfinished work even containing sensitive data and push that to the main/master branch on a remote server. Implement a real and encrypted backup solution instead!

@UlrichEckhardt this is normal for my setup. This script will only run when I use the shortcut to save and sync. I just need it in case sync breaks something important

This worked for me:

Create new script with:

echo *ssh passphrase*

Make it executable

chmod +x *pathToSctipt*

And now we can use this command to fill ssh passphrase automaticly from any script

SSH_ASKPASS="pathToScript" ssh-add *pathToSSH* < /dev/null

You put your passphrase in cleartext in a file so any cracker would read. Why not just set your key password-free?

@phd I was just wondering if this was even possible, and I also didn't know that the script would skip this part with the passphrase if it wasn't there :) But I also want to do something similar with my ssh for work, so any suggestions on how to make it more secure are welcome!
